# I am not able to do transclusion of my div tag properly in angularjs from my directive to DOM

Tags: angularjs

i tried appending my template to html div tag as shown below my app.js:-

```
myApp.directive("panel",function(){
        return{ 
                restrict:"E",
                transclude:true,
                template:'<div class=panel ng-transclude >hiii i am panel</div>'
                }
                });
```

in my html page i tried to append it to the existing html div tag as shown below:-

```
<panel>

<div class="button">click me </div>

</panel>
```

but the text in- template:'`<div class=panel ng-transclude >hiii i am panel</div>`' which is -hiii i am panel is getting hide from this button -`<div class="button">click me </div>`, iam not able to see the content inside `<div class="panel>....</div>` of the template.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you misunderstood. Transclude. Transclude means, "replace everything inside the tag that has ng-transclude on it." It is sort of like saying:

```
var content = $("panel").html();
$([ng-transclude]).html(content);
```

If you want to have *both* of them, then you need to include it separately. Try changing your template to:

```
<div class="panel"><span>hiii i am panel<span><span ng-transclude></span></div>
```

Which would show you both.

Here is a fiddle that does it http://jsfiddle.net/17nb3kg1/

Comment: what would be issue if i add ng-transclude inside my div tag <div class=panel ng-transclude > this means that this tag will get append or added to, instead of replacing everything inside it.is it not the right concept?

Comment: No, `ng-transclude` means, "replace everything inside this tag with the contents of whatever was in the directive tag."

Comment: if that is the case then i have mentioned ng-transclude in my directive div tag so this div tag is transcluded as per your say which means the div tag in my html will be replaced by this  <div class=panel ng-transclude >hiii i am panel</div>?

Comment: The other way around. The div tag in your html (inside `<panel>...</panel>` will replace `hiii i am panel`

Comment: :yes this is what i want dude,how can i display the hiii i am panel also??

Comment: Look at the answer I wrote above, and the jsfiddle. You just have to transclude deeper into the template.